# Dirichlet serie of divisors function

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, dirichlet-series, divisor-counting-function

I found on Wikipedia that
$$D(s,\sigma_a \sigma_b) := \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{\sigma_a(n)\sigma_b(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a)\zeta(s-b)\zeta(s-a-b)}{\zeta(2s-a-b)}$$

where as usual $\sigma_k(n) = \sum_{d | n} d^k$ is the $k$-th power divisors function. I do understand how to reach the Dirichlet series for $\sigma_k$, however I do not understand why is that so for the product.

Comment: $f(n) = \sigma_a(n) \sigma_b(n)$ is multiplicative. $f(p^k) =\ ?$ and $\prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1} f(p^k) p^{-sk}) =\ ?$

Comment: allo ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns It is perfect indeed, thanks !